# How to add char[item] to string?

Tags: c#

I tried with List and array Char[] but can't add this. In this case, I tried appends to `result` variable.

I want to return string `result`:

```
char[] array = valuesNew.ToCharArray();
string result = "";
for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (array[i - 1] == ' ')
    {
            array[i] = char.ToUpper(array[i]);
            result += array[i];
    }
}
return new string(result);
```

But error like:

> Cannot convert a string to char.

at line:

`return new string(result);`

Comment: *Where* is the error? I suspect you can reduce this to a shorter example. (It's also not clear why you're calling a string constructor when `result` is already a `string`.) As an aside, I'd suggest you use a `StringBuilder` rather than repeated string concatenation, unless you know for sure that the result will be very short.

Comment: as jon said: StringBuilder. OR you can convert you string to an char array, iterate through it and convert the single char you like to upper. BUT: Your code has an error: If the first char is lower case, it will never be converted to uppercase.

Comment: Do you specifically need to convert it to CharArray?

Comment: as result is already string, why don't you return result directly?: `return result;`

Comment: Am i missing something or is all you need to do is change `return new string(result);` to `return result;`. FYI the `string` constructor only accepts `char[]` which is why you are getting that error

Comment: `return result` is empty. I want to get the first character of string separate by space.

Comment: Could you give some example input/output - I still don't get what you try to achieve.

Comment: Input like: `To dO someThing in HomEWork`. and output like: `TDSIH`

Comment: @VănLộc you really need to have that example in your question next time, we can't read your mind. I believe Andrew provided an appropriate answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need the first letter of each word (using space as separator), do something like this:

```
private static string FirstLetters(string text)
{
    string[] words = text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return new string(words.Select(x => Char.ToUpper(x[0])).ToArray());
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(FirstLetters("This is a sentence.")); // Prints "TIAS"
    Console.WriteLine(FirstLetters("To dO someThing in HomEWork")); // Prints "TDSIH"
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

If for some reason you prefer not to use Linq, you can do this (doesn't work fine if there are multiple spaces next to each other):

```
private static string FirstLetters(string text)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == ' ')
            result += Char.ToUpper(text[i + 1]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(FirstLetters(" This is  a sentence.")); // Crash`

Comment: To avoid exceptions using leading/trailing nulls add `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmtpyEnries`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, although the idea was to point @VănLộc in the right direction and not create a bulletproof method. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to be in the following line -

```
return new string(result);
```

Because the `result` is of type `string`, but the `new string..` takes in char array.

But anyway as you are returning string, you can directly return `result`

EDIT: Following your comments, this should work for you -

```
        string valuesNew = "To dO someThing in HomEWork";
        char[] array = valuesNew.ToCharArray();
        string result = array[0].ToString();
        for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i - 1] == ' ')
            {
                array[i] = char.ToUpper(array[i]);
                result += array[i];
            }
        }

        return result;
```

Output is `TDSIH`

Comment: Hi @Yogi: `return result` not return any values.

Comment: @VănLộc As per your code, it will find the empty string in the `valuesNew` variable, and returns the next string value (so you need to pass string values with empty string as well), after capatalizing it. If this is not you want to do, please explain your use case in more details.

Comment: @Yogi thank you so much. It works well in case first letter is lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

If I look at the question, the array is always smaller than the string that you need to return. A string is basically a series of characters with some functionality... so why not simply modify everything in-place and create one from the `char[]`? Tools like `StringBuilder` are also an option, but they need to allocate, reallocate, etc - which is unnecessary in this case.

Here's what I came up with... not sure if it's what you mean, but it does resemble your question.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char[] array = " This is  a sentence.".ToCharArray();
    int dst = 0;

    if (array[0] != ' ' && char.IsLetter(array[0]))
    {
        array[dst++] = char.ToUpper(array[0]);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i - 1] == ' ' && char.IsLetter(array[i]))
        {
            array[dst++] = char.ToUpper(array[i]);
        }
    }
    string result = new string(array, 0, dst);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

So, why this approach?

- The OP is interested in characters, not digits and other stuff. That's pretty easy to check in a loop, especially if you want to handle more complex stuff (f.ex. '#@foo123' -- if we wanted to add a 'F' here, this is easy to implement)
- Adding characters to a string using `+=` means we have to allocate a string, copy the old one, add a character, and throw away the old string. That's an easy way to break your performance any day of the week. `StringBuilder`'s are better... but why use something like that if we already know what we want to have.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I don't know `arry[dst++] is`?

Comment: You don't know what an array, a variable and an increment is? Sorry, but I can only suggest reading a book for that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your query correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
using System.Globalization;
...
...
...
public string CapitalizeEveryWordInMyString(string input)
{
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(input);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried not using a function built in language to improve skill code.

Comment: Appreciate your choice :)

Comment: No, that would transform `To dO someThing in HomEWork` into `To Do Something In Homework` instead of `TDSIH`.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code. You can accept parameter as a input

still not clear about your requirement as you said you want first character with space.

```
public static void Main()
    {

        string test = GetString("FooBar");           

    }

    public static string GetString(string valuesNew)
    {
        //string valuesNew = "Foo";
        char[] array = valuesNew.ToCharArray();
        string result = "";

        array[0] = char.ToUpper(array[0]);
        result = array[0] + " ";

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Why loop if you will only process the first item?

Comment: as you mentioned in comment you want first character of a word with space. @Andrew, thank you for pointing this I will update my answer.

Comment: Have you tried your code? I did not, but I'd say that it returns `T ` instead of `TDSIH`.